# Robokassa, робочеки и подпись crc

Tags: php, robokassa

Не так давно Робокасса ввела решение "Робочеки", которое позволяет не заботиться о приобретении ККТ. Для того, чтобы его использовать, нужно добавить в код всего один параметр receipt ([мануал](https://docs.robokassa.ru/#6865)). И с ним большая проблема - никак не могу его правильно сформировать. Пробую что-то вроде этого:

```
$receipt = array(
    'sno' => 'usn_income',
    'items' => array(
        array(
        "name" => 'Предоплата',
        "quantity" => 1.0,
        "sum" => 300.00,
        "payment_method" => "full_payment",
        "payment_object" => "payment",
        "tax" => "none"
        )
    )
);


$encoded_receipt = json_encode($receipt);
$crc = md5("$mrh_login:$out_summ:$inv_id:$encoded_receipt:$mrh_pass1");
```

Получаю ошибку crc. Техподдержка ответила следующее:

```
Необходимо добиться такого вида -

receipt={"sno": "usn_income","items":[{"name":"Предоплата экскурсии","quantity":1.0,"sum":300.00,"payment_method":"full_payment","payment_object":"payment","tax":"none"}]}
```

И теперь вопрос: как добиться такого вида на php? Пробовал и так, и сяк, получаю ошибку. Может быть, как-то неправильно вкладываю объекты/массивы.

В общем, если кто-то уже реализовывал подобное решение Робокассы на php, помогите, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Есть объекты `{ .. }`, а есть массивы `[ .. ]`. Объекты в PHP это экземпляры классов.

В простом варианте собрать можно так:

```java
$receipt = new stdClass();
$receipt->sno = 'usn_income';
$receipt->items = [];

$item = new stdClass();
$item->name = 'Предоплата';
$item->quantity = 1.0;
$item->sum = 300.00;
$item->payment_method = "full_payment";
$item->payment_object = "payment";
$item->tax = "none";

$receipt->items[] = $item;

$encoded_receipt = json_encode($receipt, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Что бы не собирать объекты вручную можно сразу читать объект из базы (или десериализовать из API) в объект. А избежать рутины можно если использовать библиотеки сериалайзеров, например [JmsSerializer](https://www.jmsyst.com/libs/serializer)

Comment: Вообще-то и ассоциативный массив и объект закодируются в одинаковую json-строку.

Comment: @u_mulder, тогда прокоментируйте результат вот [этого кода](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4133453c875ec49b614e5e23c68ec2de6797e030)

Comment: Я не вижу здесь ассоциативного массива.

Comment: @u_mulder, редачер, было написано про массив. Всё что не начинается с нуля является ассоциативным массивом, тут можно хорошо попасться, поэтому предпочитаю stdClass.

Comment: Я не знаю что такое редачер. Было изначально написано про __ассоциативный__ массив. У модифицированных сообщений стоит карандашик.